# Как повлиять на элементы при :hover за холстом при рисовании следа мыши

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, hover

У меня есть 8 столбцов `flex-box`, где при наведении курсора на них будут отображаться изображения. Я хочу оставлять следы при перемещении мыши по экрану, поэтому я использовал `onmousemove`, чтобы рисовать линии на холсте. Однако, когда я кладу свой холст поверх столбцов, наведение курсора на столбцы для отображения фотографий больше не работает. Как оставить след от линии мыши, чтобы изображения появлялись при наведении курсора на столбцы?

```
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="c" width="100%" height="100%" ></canvas>
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col" id="col1" >
             <img class="media-overlay col-1 left top" id="img1" 
             src="imgs/port2.jpg" alt="port2" />
       </div>
       <div class="col" id="col2">
             <img class="media-overlay col-1 left bottom  " id="img2" 
             src="imgs/port1.jpg" alt="port1" />
             </div>
 
        <div class="col" id="col3">
              <img class="media-overlay col-2 right top" 
              src="imgs/land1.jpg" id="img3" alt="land1" />
         </div>
 
  </div>
```

```
<script> // this draws the line that follows the mouse movements
const pathes = []; // this is where we will store all our pathes
let mouse_down = false; // shall we draw ?
c.onmouseover = e => {
  // add a new path object
  pathes.push({
    pts: [], // an array of points
    dashed: check.checked // boolean
  });
  mouse_down = true; // we should draw
}
c.onmouseup = c.onmouseleave = e => mouse_down = false;

c.onmousemove = throttle(e => {
  if (!mouse_down) {
    return;
  } else {
    const rec = c.getBoundingClientRect();
    // add a new point
    addPoint(e.clientX - rec.left, e.clientY - rec.top);
    redraw(); // redraw everything
  }
});

function redraw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); // we clear everything
  // and draw every pathes
  pathes.forEach(path => {
    ctx.setLineDash(path.dashed ? [5, 5] : [0]);
    // set line color
    // ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF';
    ctx.beginPath();
    path.pts.forEach(pt => ctx.lineTo(pt.x, pt.y));
    ctx.stroke();
  })
}

function addPoint(x, y) {
  // append to the last one
  const points = pathes[pathes.length - 1].pts;
  points.push({
    x: x,
    y: y
  });
}


// just to avoid unnecessary drawings
function throttle(callback) {
  if (typeof callback !== 'function')
    throw 'A callback function must be passed';
  var active = false;
  var evt;
  var handler = function() {
    active = false;
    callback(evt);
  };
  return function handleEvent(e) {
    evt = e;
    if (!active) {
      active = true;
      requestAnimationFrame(handler);
    }
  };
}
```

```
//css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
height:100%;                    
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.col {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;  
}
img.media-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
}
  
.col:hover img {
  display: block;
}
canvas {
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  z-index: 1;

 
}
```

```js
// this draws the line that follows the mouse movements
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const pathes = []; // this is where we will store all our pathes
let mouse_down = false; // shall we draw ?
c.onmouseover = e => {
  // add a new path object
  pathes.push({
    pts: [], // an array of points
    dashed: true // boolean
  });
  mouse_down = true; // we should draw
}
c.onmouseup = c.onmouseleave = e => mouse_down = false;

c.onmousemove = throttle(e => {
  if (!mouse_down) {
    return;
  } else {
    const rec = c.getBoundingClientRect();
    // add a new point
    addPoint(e.clientX - rec.left, e.clientY - rec.top);
    redraw(); // redraw everything
  }
});

function redraw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); // we clear everything
  // and draw every pathes
  pathes.forEach(path => {
    ctx.setLineDash(path.dashed ? [5, 5] : [0]);
    // set line color
    // ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF';
    ctx.beginPath();
    path.pts.forEach(pt => ctx.lineTo(pt.x, pt.y));
    ctx.stroke();
  })
}

function addPoint(x, y) {
  // append to the last one
  const points = pathes[pathes.length - 1].pts;
  points.push({
    x: x,
    y: y
  });
}


// just to avoid unnecessary drawings
function throttle(callback) {
  if (typeof callback !== 'function')
    throw 'A callback function must be passed';
  var active = false;
  var evt;
  var handler = function() {
    active = false;
    callback(evt);
  };
  return function handleEvent(e) {
    evt = e;
    if (!active) {
      active = true;
      requestAnimationFrame(handler);
    }
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.col {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

img.media-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.col:hover img {
  display: block;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="c" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="col1">
      <img class="media-overlay col-1 left top" id="img1" src="imgs/port2.jpg" alt="port2" />
    </div>
    <div class="col" id="col2">
      <img class="media-overlay col-1 left bottom  " id="img2" src="imgs/port1.jpg" alt="port1" />
    </div>

    <div class="col" id="col3">
      <img class="media-overlay col-2 right top" src="imgs/land1.jpg" id="img3" alt="land1" />
    </div>

  </div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [how to affect hover elements behind canvas when drawing mouse trail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63009606/7394871) от участника  [@saltykiam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13163338/saltykiam).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63009606/7394871

Comment: Немного доработал, чтобы бы был рабочий сниппет. Если не то, то удали))

Comment: Саш, я для тя нашел новый  [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1356348/Помогите-данный-прелодер-на-css-переписать-на-svg)

Comment: @Air Спасибо, интересный вопрос, попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устанавливаю размер `canvas` по размеру `div` (контейнер). Для игнорирования действий мыши на `canvas` добавляю `pointer-events: none`. Колонки (здесь sections) для простоты подкрашиваю в красный, но можно добавить любую логику `onhover`.

При `window.onresize` размер холста меняется, а данные по прежним путям удаляются.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let w, h;
let points;

div.addEventListener('mousemove', addPoint);
window.addEventListener('resize', setCanvas);
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setCanvas);

function setCanvas() {
  points = [];

  const rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
  w = canvas.width = rect.width;
  h = canvas.height = rect.height;

  ctx.setLineDash([5, 5]);
}

function addPoint(event) {
  points.push([event.layerX, event.layerY]);
  drawDashedLine();
}

function drawDashedLine() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  let path_string = `M ${points[0][0]} ${points[0][1]} L`
  for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    path_string += ` ${points[i][0]} ${points[i][1]}`;
  }
  const path = new Path2D(path_string);
  ctx.stroke(path);
}
```

```css
div {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</div>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Зачёт Может попробуешь добавить ещё появление изображений при наведении, как в вопросе

Comment: Я просто не понимаю почему авторы вопросов не побеспокоятся о небитых ссылках на изображения, можно со специальных сайтов набирать. А я вот сиди и наковыривай изображения, проблемы то нет преобразовать как угодно уже элементы. Можно хоть загрузить изображений в темную и нарезать через холст нужного размера, можно через css назначить `background-image`. Проблема была в натягивании холста поверх множества элементов и перекидывания координат на холст, а также "пропуск" событий мыши на нижележащий слой. И эта задача решена. И пропусков в путях у меня нет)))

Comment: Ну вот такие они авторы вопросов

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить всех слушателей событий к элементу `#container` вместо холста, я предполагаю, что холст такой же ширины и высоты.

При добавлении `pointer-events:none;` к вашему элементу холста. Это свойство отменяет все пользовательские события на текущем слое и передает их элементам ниже.

```js
// ====================== drawing canvas
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
const $container= document.querySelector('#container');

 // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
 window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

 function resizeCanvas() {
         c.width = window.innerWidth;
         c.height = window.innerHeight;

         /**
          * Your drawings need to be inside this function otherwise they will be reset when 
          * you resize the browser window and the canvas goes will be cleared.
          */
         drawStuff(); 
 }
 resizeCanvas();

 function drawStuff() {
         // do your drawing stuff here//
         const pathes = []; // this is where we will store all our pathes
          let mouse_down = false; // shall we draw ?
          $container.onmouseover = e => {
            // add a new path object
            pathes.push({
              pts: [], // an array of points
              dashed: check.checked // boolean
            });
            mouse_down = true; // we should draw
          }
          $container.onmouseup = c.onmouseleave = e => mouse_down = false;

          $container.onmousemove = throttle(e => {
            if (!mouse_down) {
              return;
            } else {
              const rec = c.getBoundingClientRect();
              // add a new point
              addPoint(e.clientX - rec.left, e.clientY - rec.top);
              redraw(); // redraw everything
            }
          });

          function redraw() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); // we clear everything
            // and draw every pathes
            pathes.forEach(path => {
              ctx.setLineDash(path.dashed ? [5, 5] : [0]);
              // set line color
              // ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF';
              ctx.beginPath();
              path.pts.forEach(pt => ctx.lineTo(pt.x, pt.y));
              ctx.stroke();
            })
          }

          function addPoint(x, y) {
            // append to the last one
            const points = pathes[pathes.length - 1].pts;
            points.push({
              x: x,
              y: y
            });
          }


          // just to avoid unnecessary drawings
          function throttle(callback) {
            if (typeof callback !== 'function')
              throw 'A callback function must be passed';
            var active = false;
            var evt;
            var handler = function() {
              active = false;
              callback(evt);
            };
            return function handleEvent(e) {
              evt = e;
              if (!active) {
                active = true;
                requestAnimationFrame(handler);
              }
            };
          }
          }


//================ рандомизация столбцов ====================

let mediaElements = [...document.getElementsByClassName("col")];

// здесь вы назначаете массив для списка src (или рандомизируете его)
//array.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)

//поместить диапазон в массив
function range(start, end) {
    var ans = [];
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        ans.push(i);
    }
    return ans;
}

//перемешать массив
function shuffle(array) {
  return array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}

//теперь случайный порядок
let orderNumber = range(1, mediaElements.length);
let shuffled = shuffle(orderNumber);
//console.log(shuffled); // [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]

//назначить порядок как-то 
mediaElements.forEach(y => {
  // здесь вы добавляете или src
  // y - это каждый из img
  //console.log(y)
  y.style.order = shuffled.shift()
});
```

```css
/* canvas {
  border: 1px solid;

} */

/* Файлы CSS добавляют правила стиля к вашему контенту */
html {
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  /* background-color: black;  */
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.col {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border-right: 0.5px #EDE7DD solid;
  border-top: 0.5px #EDE7DD solid;
  border-bottom: 0.5px #EDE7DD solid;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
/* .col:hover {
  background-color: pink;
} */

img.media-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  border-bottom: 0.5px #EDE7DD solid;
  border-top: 0.5px #EDE7DD solid;
}

.col:hover img {
  display: block;
} 



img.col-1 {
  max-width: 300px;
}

img.col-2 {
  max-width: 600.5px;
  /* add border width 600 */
}

img.left {
  left: 0;
}

img.right {
  right: 0;
}

img.top {
  top: 0;
  border-top: 0px black solid;
}

img.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 0px black solid;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  /* ==============
  строка занимает весь экран
  нужно также позаботиться об изображениях или наложениях мультимедиа
  ============== */
  .col {
    width: 100%;
  }

  /* ==============
  столбцы превращаются в строки
   нужно также позаботиться об изображениях или наложениях мультимедиа
ширина рядов и границы (внизу)
  ============== */
  /* .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  } */
}

h3 {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #EDE7DD;
  /* color:#FFC6C0; */

  font-family: nimbus-sans, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

p {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #EDE7DD;

  font-family: nimbus-sans, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

.bottomText {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events:none;
  /* overflow: auto; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Hello!</title>

    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

    <!-- nimbus sans -->
    <!-- bold -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/oub0bcu.css" />

    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check" checked style="display:none"/></label
    ><br />

    <div class="container" id='container'>
      <canvas id="c" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
      <div class="row" id="row">

    <div class="col" id="col1">
      <h3>Abbie Lilley & Indiya Tupe</h3>
      <p>
        “Unearth is a campaign intending to inspire a deeper exploration and richer interactions with our surroundings
        in order to apprehend a deeper embrace of natural and urban environments. Animating the lyrics of Nothing but
        Flowers by Talking Heads, playful juxtapositions are at the heart of our environmental centred campaign;
        investigating a place’s potential to transform typographic led interventions and inform visual language.”</p>
      <img class="media-overlay col-1 left top" id="img1" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/b8a16f28-5a0d-40f6-bede-673c5c7bf326%2Fport2.jpg?v=1595172025095" alt="port2" />
    </div>

    <div class="col " id="col2">
      <img class="media-overlay col-1 left bottom  " id="img2" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/b8a16f28-5a0d-40f6-bede-673c5c7bf326%2Fport1.jpg?v=1595172012754" alt="port1" />
      <div class= "bottomText">
        <h3>Mayli Mountford</h3>
        <p>
          “An unconventional rebrand of 'Britishness' so it accurately represents contemporary ’British' Identity to
          promote and represent all people and culture in the United Kingdom. An aspect I decided to rebrand was British
          slang and language - there are typical British sayings but I knew there are other sayings from other cultures
          that are spoken in the UK.
          <br><br>People of different ethnicities have been born, grown up here, and consider themselves British and yet
          the British identity does not represent them? Maybe Britain wouldn’t be so divided, if Britain actually
          represented Britain?
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col" id="col3">
      <img class="media-overlay col-2 right top" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/b8a16f28-5a0d-40f6-bede-673c5c7bf326%2Fland1.jpg?v=1595171993148" id="img3" alt="land1" />

      <h3>3</h3>
      <p></p>


    </div>
    <div class="col" id="col4">
      <img class="media-overlay col-1 right bottom " src="https://cdn.glitch.com/b8a16f28-5a0d-40f6-bede-673c5c7bf326%2Fport4.jpeg?v=1595172032309" id="img4" alt="port3" />

      <h3>4</h3>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col" id="col5">
       <img class="media-overlay col-2 right top" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/b8a16f28-5a0d-40f6-bede-673c5c7bf326%2Fland2.png?v=1595172018931" id="img5" alt="land2" />

      <h3>5</h3>
      <p></p>
      
    </div>
    <div class="col" id="col6">
      <img class="media-overlay col-2 right top" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/b8a16f28-5a0d-40f6-bede-673c5c7bf326%2Fland2.png?v=1595172018931" id="img6" alt="land2" />

      <h3>6</h3>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col" id="col7">
      <img class="media-overlay col-2 right top" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/b8a16f28-5a0d-40f6-bede-673c5c7bf326%2Fport4.jpeg?v=1595172032309" id="img7" alt="land2" />

      <h3>7</h3>
      <p></p>

    </div>
    <div class="col" id="col8">
      <img class="media-overlay col-2 right top" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/b8a16f28-5a0d-40f6-bede-673c5c7bf326%2Fport4.jpeg?v=1595172032309" id="img8" alt="land2" />

      <h3>8</h3>
      <p></p>

    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63009678/7394871) от участника  [@t1m0n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1651018/t1m0n).</sub>

Comment: Куча кода, а что-то не так))) Есть пропуски при быстром перемещении мышью на границах элементов. Что именно добавил автор не сразу понятно, свойство `pointer-events:none;`, а остальное зачем?)))

Comment: @Leonid если есть желание, прокачай, дай свой ответ

Comment: Я такого миллиона-кода боюсь)) Мало ли что там автор хотел, он ведь даже не растянул холст поверх всех элементов. Короче здесь вопрос про CSS, а не про canvas получается.

Comment: @Leonid а ты зайди с другой стороны. Задача из вопроса ясна? Пиши свой код, 
 с чистого листа, не обращая внимания на ответ. Ну конечно это всё по желанию и наличию времени.