# Помогите данный прелодер на css переписать на svg?

Tags: css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Главное,  чтобы данный прелодер одинаковый вид при любом расширении, плюс надо чтобы символы тоже имели градиент. Можно конечно этого добиться на `css`, но все же это будет уже извращением...

Заранее благодарю за помощь...

```js
document.querySelector(".circle").innerHTML = "Loading..."
  .split("")
  .map((e, i) => `<span style="--rot:${i * 11}deg">${e}</span>`)
  .join("");
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
  color: burlywood;
  font-size: 2vw;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

body * {
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

.circle {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle::after,
.circle::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*
        */
}

.circle::after {
  animation: rott 1s ease infinite;
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, red 20%, purple 70%);
  background-position: -42px -29px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 30px solid #272727;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  background-size: 132% 120%;
}

.circle::before {
  background-color: #272727;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 4;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: calc(20vw - 30px);
  height: calc(20vw - 30px);
}

span {
  z-index: 9;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 60px 0 0 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: 6px 56% 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(var(--rot));
}

span:nth-child(8) {
  animation: opa 1s ease 0s infinite;
}

span:nth-child(9) {
  animation: opa 1s ease 0.2s infinite;
}

span:nth-child(10) {
  animation: opa 1s ease 0.5s infinite;
}

@keyframes rott {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes opa {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: а если все это поместить в маску в которой будет градиент ... и пущай она крутиться вертится  ...

Comment: Айболит, друг мой, как твоей душе угодно....  Главное, что бы работало...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Из окружности вырезается дуга с помощью `stroke-dasharray`
- Дуга окрашивается линейным градиентом
- Дуга вращается с помощью изменения атрибутов `stroke-dashoffset`
- Неравномерность вращения реализуется `keyTimes="0;0.75;0.9;1"`
- Расположение текста `Loading ...` по дуге за счет применения
  `<textPath href="#textPath" startOffset="12">`

```css
body {
background:#272727;
}
.container {
width:40vw;
height:40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="0 0 400 400"  > 
 <defs>    
                <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски дуги с прозрачным хвостом -->
   <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.05"  />
      <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="red"  />
   </linearGradient>
 </defs>    
                  <!-- Дуга, на которой расположены буквы  -->
<path id="textPath" d="M200,110 A90,90 0 0 1 200,290" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
<text class="txt1" font-size="32px" letter-spacing="0.2em" fill="#DEB887">
  <textPath href="#textPath" startOffset="12">
    <tspan dy="-0.1em">Loading . . .</tspan>
  </textPath>
</text>
                         <!-- Вращающаяся дуга -->
<circle id="circle" cx="200" cy="200" r="150" stroke="url(#Lg)" stroke-width="20" stroke-dashoffset="942"  stroke-dasharray="471" fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-linecap="round" >
    <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     begin="0s" dur="1s"
     values="942;471;235;0"
     keyTimes="0;0.75;0.9;1"
      calcMode="linear"
     repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  
</circle> 
</svg>
</div>
```

### Update

Добавлена анимация текста **Loading ...**

Реализовано с помощью маски-полукруга, который вращается и тем самым открывает, маскирует текст

```
<mask id="mask">    
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
       <path transform="rotate(0,200,200)" d="M200,90 A110,110 0 0 1 200,310" stroke-width="20" fill="black" stroke="black" >  
      <animateTransform
     attributeName="transform"
     type="rotate"
     begin="0s" dur="4s"
     values="0,200,200;360,200,200"
     repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
     </path>    
</mask>
```

```css
body {
background:#272727;
}
.container {
width:40vw;
height:40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 400"  > 
 <defs>
   <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.05"  />
      <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="red"  />
        
   </linearGradient> 
   <mask id="mask">    
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
       <path transform="rotate(0,200,200)" d="M200,90 A110,110 0 0 1 200,310" stroke-width="20" fill="black" stroke="black" >  
      <animateTransform
     attributeName="transform"
     type="rotate"
     begin="0s" dur="4s"
     values="0,200,200;360,200,200"
     repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
     </path>    
   </mask>
 </defs>         
<path   id="textPath" d="M200,110 A90,90 0 0 1 200,290" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
<text  mask="url(#mask)" class="txt1" font-size="32px" letter-spacing="0.2em" fill="#DEB887">
  <textPath href="#textPath" startOffset="12">
    <tspan dy="-0.1em">Loading . . .</tspan>
  </textPath>
</text>
  
<circle id="circle" cx="200" cy="200" r="150" stroke="url(#Lg)" stroke-width="20" stroke-dashoffset="942"  stroke-dasharray="471" fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-linecap="round" >
    <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     begin="0s" dur="1s"
     values="942;471;235;0"
     keyTimes="0;0.75;0.9;1"
      calcMode="linear"
     repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  
</circle> 
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю......

Comment: @Air На здоровье, Всегда рад тебе помочь :)

Comment: Саш, а почему не могу этот же градиент использовать для цвета текста?  Не работает `fill="#Lg"`  или я не прав?

Comment: ок..............

Comment: @Air присваивается же градиент => https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/KKXpamr

Comment: @Айболит, благодарю, я  `URL()` пропустил

Answer (score 2):

### Варианты с анимацией градиента

В градиенте анимируется атрибут `offset` у обоих составляющих градиент цветов:

```
                  <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски текста -->
<linearGradient id="LgText" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0.25" y2="1">
  <stop offset="5%" stop-color="orangered"  >
      <animate attributeName="offset" dur="3s" values="0;1;1" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </stop>
   <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#DEB887" >
      <animate attributeName="offset" dur="3s" values="0;1;1" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
   </stop>
</linearGradient>
```

при значении `values="0;1;1"` повторение `1` обеспечивает паузу в конце закраски

```css
body {
background:#272727;
}
.container {
width:40vw;
height:40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 400"  > 
 <defs>    
                <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски дуги с прозрачным хвостом -->
   <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.05"  />
      <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="red"  />
   </linearGradient> 
                   <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски текста -->
<linearGradient id="LgText" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0.25" y2="1">
  <stop offset="5%" stop-color="orangered"  >
      <animate attributeName="offset" dur="3s" values="0;1;1" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </stop>
   <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#DEB887" >
      <animate attributeName="offset" dur="3s" values="0;1;1" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
   </stop>
</linearGradient> 
 </defs>    
                  <!-- Дуга, на которой расположены буквы  -->
<path id="textPath" d="M200,110 A90,90 0 0 1 200,290" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
<text class="txt1" font-size="36px" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="0.2em" fill="url(#LgText)">
  <textPath href="#textPath" startOffset="2">
    <tspan dy="-0.1em">Loading . . .</tspan>
  </textPath>
</text>
                         <!-- Вращающаяся дуга -->
<circle id="circle" cx="200" cy="200" r="150" stroke="url(#Lg)" stroke-width="20" stroke-dashoffset="942"  stroke-dasharray="471" fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-linecap="round" >
    <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     begin="0s" dur="1s"
     values="942;471;235;0"
     keyTimes="0;0.75;0.9;1"
      calcMode="linear"
     repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  
</circle> 
</svg>
</div>
```

При `values="0;1;1;0;0"` будет закраска в обе стороны с паузой в конечных позициях

```css
body {
background:#272727;
}
.container {
width:40vw;
height:40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 400"  > 
 <defs>    
                <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски дуги с прозрачным хвостом -->
   <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.05"  />
      <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="red"  />
   </linearGradient> 
                   <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски текста -->
   <linearGradient id="LgText" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0.25" y2="1">
  <stop offset="5%" stop-color="orangered"  >
      <animate attributeName="offset" dur="6s" values="0;1;1;0;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
    </stop>
   <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#DEB887" >
      <animate attributeName="offset" dur="6s" values="0;1;1;0;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
   </stop>
   
 </linearGradient> 
 </defs>    
                  <!-- Дуга, на которой расположены буквы  -->
<path id="textPath" d="M200,110 A90,90 0 0 1 200,290" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
<text class="txt1" font-size="36px" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="0.2em" fill="url(#LgText)">
  <textPath href="#textPath" startOffset="2">
    <tspan dy="-0.1em">Loading . . .</tspan>
  </textPath>
</text>
                         <!-- Вращающаяся дуга -->
<circle id="circle" cx="200" cy="200" r="150" stroke="url(#Lg)" stroke-width="20" stroke-dashoffset="942"  stroke-dasharray="471" fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-linecap="round" >
    <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     begin="0s" dur="1s"
     values="942;471;235;0"
     keyTimes="0;0.75;0.9;1"
      calcMode="linear"
     repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  
</circle> 
</svg>
</div>
```

### Update

Цитата из комментария @Air:

> Например, что бы полоса была на одном уровне с надписью, и проходила
> через нее... По сути, полоса с градиентом доходя до границы надписи и
> исчезала, как бы входила в нее и выходила из нее в конце... было бы
> прикольно

Идея сделать буквы прозрачными, только строка с очертанием буквы, включить их в маску и применить эту маску к вращающейся дуге

- Вариант с закраской градиентом в одну сторону

```css
body {
background:#272727;
}
.container {
width:40vw;
height:40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 400"  > 
 <defs>    
                <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски дуги с прозрачным хвостом -->
   <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.05"  />
      <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="red"  />
   </linearGradient> 
                   <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски текста -->
   <linearGradient id="LgText" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0.25" y2="1">
  <stop offset="5%" stop-color="orangered"  >
      <animate attributeName="offset" dur="2s" values="0;1" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
    </stop>
   <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#DEB887" >
      <animate attributeName="offset" dur="2s" values="0;1" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
   </stop>
   
 </linearGradient> 
 </defs>    

                         <!-- Вращающаяся дуга -->
<circle id="circle" cx="200" cy="200" r="150" stroke="url(#Lg)" stroke-width="42" stroke-dashoffset="942"  stroke-dasharray="471" fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-linecap="round" >
    <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     begin="0s" dur="1s"
     values="942;471;235;0"
     keyTimes="0;0.75;0.9;1"
      calcMode="linear"
     repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  
</circle> 
                    <!-- Дуга, на которой расположены буквы  -->
<path id="textPath" d="M200,110 A90,90 0 0 1 200,290" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
<text class="txt1" font-size="36px" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="0.2em" fill="url(#LgText)" stroke="#DEB887" >
  <textPath href="#textPath" startOffset="2">
    <tspan dy="-1.3em">Loading . . .</tspan>
  </textPath>
</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

- Вариант с закраской градиентом в обе стороны

```css
body {
background:#272727;
}
.container {
width:40vw;
height:40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 400"  > 
 <defs>    
                <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски дуги с прозрачным хвостом -->
   <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.05"  />
      <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="red"  />
   </linearGradient> 
                   <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски текста -->
   <linearGradient id="LgText" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0.25" y2="1">
  <stop offset="5%" stop-color="orangered"  >
      <animate attributeName="offset" dur="6s" values="0;1;1;0;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
    </stop>
   <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#DEB887" >
      <animate attributeName="offset" dur="6s" values="0;1;1;0;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
   </stop>
   
 </linearGradient> 
 <mask id="mask">
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
   <g fill="black"> 
       <path id="textPath" d="M200,110 A90,90 0 0 1 200,290"  fill="black" stroke="none" /> 
<text class="txt1" font-size="36px" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="0.2em"  stroke="black" >
  <textPath href="#textPath" startOffset="2">
    <tspan dy="-1.3em">Loading . . .</tspan>
  </textPath>
</text>
   </g>
 </mask>
 </defs>      
 
                     <!-- Дуга, на которой расположены буквы  -->
<path id="textPath" d="M200,110 A90,90 0 0 1 200,290" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
<text class="txt1" font-size="36px" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="0.2em" fill="url(#LgText)" stroke="#DEB887" >
  <textPath href="#textPath" startOffset="2">
    <tspan dy="-1.3em">Loading . . .</tspan>
  </textPath>
</text>

                         <!-- Вращающаяся дуга -->
<circle id="circle" cx="200" cy="200" r="150" mask="url(#mask)" stroke="url(#Lg)" stroke-width="42" stroke-dashoffset="942"  stroke-dasharray="471" fill="none"  stroke-linecap="round" >
    <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     begin="0s" dur="1s"
     values="942;471;235;0"
     keyTimes="0;0.75;0.9;1"
      calcMode="linear"
     repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  
</circle> 

</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Саш, ты в своей стихии....  Мне нравиться... Кстати, можно еще кое что придумать...  Например, что бы полоса была на одном уровне с надписью, и проходила через нее... По сути, полоса с градиентом доходя до границы надписи и исчезала, как бы входила в нее и выходила из нее в конце... было бы прикольно

Comment: Но при этом анимация градиента должна быть и в самой надписи

Comment: Да нет, я сам писал....

Comment: @Air посмотри  [новый ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1356822/28748) вроде сделал, как ты хотел