# Как добиться, чтобы цветной градиент двигающейся полосы подсвечивал текст снизу

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, svg-animation

Вопрос инициирован [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1356614/28748) и [комментарием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1356348/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-css-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-svg/1356614#) на него

> Например, что бы полоса была на одном уровне с надписью, и проходила
> через нее... По сути, полоса с градиентом доходя до границы надписи и
> исчезала, как бы входила в нее и выходила из нее в конце... было бы
> прикольно

Вот собственно код:

```css
body {
background:#272727;
}
.container {
width:40vw;
height:40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 400"  > 
 <defs>    
                <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски дуги с прозрачным хвостом -->
   <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.05"  />
      <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="red"  />
   </linearGradient> 
                   <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски текста -->
   <linearGradient id="LgText" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0.25" y2="1">
  <stop offset="5%" stop-color="orangered"  >
      <animate attributeName="offset" dur="6s" values="0;1;1;0;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
    </stop>
   <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#DEB887" >
      <animate attributeName="offset" dur="6s" values="0;1;1;0;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
   </stop>
   
 </linearGradient> 
 <mask id="mask">
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
   <g fill="black"> 
       <path id="textPath" d="M200,110 A90,90 0 0 1 200,290"  fill="black" stroke="none" /> 
<text class="txt1" font-size="36px" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="0.2em"  stroke="black" >
  <textPath href="#textPath" startOffset="2">
    <tspan dy="-1.3em">Loading . . .</tspan>
  </textPath>
</text>
   </g>
 </mask>
 </defs>      
 
                     <!-- Дуга, на которой расположены буквы  -->
<path id="textPath" d="M200,110 A90,90 0 0 1 200,290" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
<text class="txt1" font-size="36px" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="0.2em" fill="url(#LgText)" stroke="#DEB887" >
  <textPath href="#textPath" startOffset="2">
    <tspan dy="-1.3em">Loading . . .</tspan>
  </textPath>
</text>

                         <!-- Вращающаяся дуга -->
<circle id="circle" cx="200" cy="200" r="150" mask="url(#mask)" stroke="url(#Lg)" stroke-width="42" stroke-dashoffset="942"  stroke-dasharray="471" fill="none"  stroke-linecap="round" >
    <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     begin="0s" dur="1s"
     values="942;471;235;0"
     keyTimes="0;0.75;0.9;1"
      calcMode="linear"
     repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  
</circle> 

</svg>
</div>
```

По коду видно, что градиентная полоса проходит под текстом **Loading . . .**  и буквы имеют свой динамический градиент, но всё это работает немного не так, как описано в комментарии автора вопроса

Нет синхронизации градиента полосы и букв. Полосу видно, когда она проходит под буквами.

Как добиться выполнения условий, изложенных в комментарии см. ваше

Answer (score 5):

### Идея решения следующая:

1. Необходимо скрыть часть трассы движения цветной полосы
2. Буквы должны быть прозрачными, оставить только контур
3. Применить текстовую маску **Loading ...**, которая бы прорезала закрытый (экранированный) участок трассы движения цветной полосы, тем самым сквозь прозрачные буквы будет видна цветная полоса и на буквах будет виден динамический градиент.

***#1.*** Экранирование части трассы движения цветной полосы

Для этого добавляем поверх трассы движения цветного бегунка экранирующий сегмент

```css
body {
background:#272727;
}
.container {
width:40vw;
height:40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 400" > 
 <defs>    
                <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски дуги с прозрачным хвостом -->
   <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.05"  />
      <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="red"  />
   </linearGradient> 
 </defs>      
                          <!-- Вращающаяся дуга с градиентом -->
<circle id="circle" cx="200" cy="200" r="150"  stroke="url(#Lg)" stroke-width="45" stroke-dashoffset="942"  stroke-dasharray="471" fill="none"  stroke-linecap="round" >
    <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     begin="0s" dur="1s"
     values="942;471;235;0"
     keyTimes="0;0.75;0.9;1"
      calcMode="linear"
     repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  
</circle> 
 
              <!-- Поверх трассы цветного бегунка -->
    <path id="textPath"  d="M200 50a150 150 0 0 1 0 300"   fill="none"   stroke="#383838" stroke-width="45" stroke-linecap="round" opacity="0.9"/>
  
</svg> 
</div>
```

***#2.*** Добавляем надпись сверху экранирующей полосы

Чтобы буквы были прозрачными `fill="none"` и был только контур `stroke="gold"`

```css
body {
background:#272727;
}
.container {
width:40vw;
height:40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 400" > 
 <defs>    
                <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски дуги с прозрачным хвостом -->
   <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.05"  />
      <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="red"  />
   </linearGradient> 
 </defs>      
                          <!-- Вращающаяся дуга с градиентом -->
<circle id="circle" cx="200" cy="200" r="150"  stroke="url(#Lg)" stroke-width="45" stroke-dashoffset="942"  stroke-dasharray="471" fill="none"  stroke-linecap="round" >
    <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     begin="0s" dur="1s"
     values="942;471;235;0"
     keyTimes="0;0.75;0.9;1"
      calcMode="linear"
     repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  
</circle> 
 
              <!-- Экранирующая полоса поверх трассы цветного бегунка  -->
    <path id="textPath"  d="M200 50a150 150 0 0 1 0 300"   fill="none"   stroke="#383838" stroke-width="45" stroke-linecap="round" opacity="0.9"/>  
    
    
  <path id="textPath1" d="M200 50a150 150 0 0 1 0 300"    fill="none"   /> 
           <!-- Будущая текстовая маска -->
<text class="txt1" font-size="38px" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="0.5em"  stroke="gold" stroke-width="2" >
  <textPath href="#textPath1" startOffset="1">
    <tspan dy="0.35em">Loading . . .</tspan>
  </textPath>
</text>
  
  
</svg> 
</div>
```

***#3.*** Применяем текстовую маску Loading ...,

которая  прорезает закрытый (экранированный) участок трассы движения цветной полосы и становится виден динамический градиент

```
<mask id="mask">
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
   <g fill="black"> 
       <path id="textPath" d="M200,110 A90,90 0 0 1 200,290"  fill="black" stroke="none" /> 
<text class="txt1" font-size="36px" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="0.2em"  stroke="black" >
  <textPath href="#textPath" startOffset="2">
    <tspan dy="-1.3em">Loading . . .</tspan>
  </textPath>
</text>
   </g>
 </mask>
```

Для текстовой маски закраска `<g fill="black">` при этом значении она прорезает экранирующую полосу
подробней как работает маска [тут](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1862)
Применяем маску `mask="url(#mask)"`

```css
body {
background:#272727;
}
.container {
width:40vw;
height:40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 400"  > 
 <defs>    
                <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски дуги с прозрачным хвостом -->
   <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.05"  />
      <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="red"  />
   </linearGradient> 
                   <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски текста -->
   <linearGradient id="LgText" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0.25" y2="1">
  <stop offset="5%" stop-color="orangered"  >
      <animate attributeName="offset" dur="6s" values="0;1;1;0;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
    </stop>
   <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#DEB887" >
      <animate attributeName="offset" dur="6s" values="0;1;1;0;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
   </stop>
   
 </linearGradient> 
 <mask id="mask">
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
   <g fill="black"> 
       <path id="textPath" d="M200,110 A90,90 0 0 1 200,290"  fill="black" stroke="none" /> 
<text class="txt1" font-size="36px" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="0.2em"  stroke="black" >
  <textPath href="#textPath" startOffset="2">
    <tspan dy="-1.3em">Loading . . .</tspan>
  </textPath>
</text>
   </g>
 </mask>
 </defs>      
 

                         <!-- Вращающаяся дуга -->
<circle id="circle" cx="200" cy="200" r="150"  stroke="url(#Lg)" stroke-width="42" stroke-dashoffset="942"  stroke-dasharray="471" fill="none"  stroke-linecap="round" >
    <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     begin="0s" dur="1s"
     values="942;471;235;0"
     keyTimes="0;0.75;0.9;1"
      calcMode="linear"
     repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  
</circle>   
 
             <!-- Экранирующая полоса применяем к ней маску  -->
    <path id="textPath" mask="url(#mask)"  d="M200 50a150 150 0 0 1 0 300"   fill="none"   stroke="#383838" stroke-width="45" stroke-linecap="round" />  

</svg>
</div>
```

Маска неожиданно подрезала края, хотя она была применена только к буквам

***Устраняем этот дефект*** путем добавления [maskUnits="objectBoundingBox"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/maskContentUnits) и расширяем регион действия маски   `x="0%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="150%"`

```css
body {
background:#272727;
}
.container {
width:40vw;
height:40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 400"  > 
 <defs>    
                <!-- Линейный градиент для окраски дуги с прозрачным хвостом -->
   <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.05"  />
      <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="red"  />
   </linearGradient> 
 
 <mask id="mask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox"
        x="0%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="150%">
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
   <g fill="black"> 
        <path id="textPath1" d="M200 50a150 150 0 0 1 0 300"    fill="none"   /> 
           <!-- текстовая маска -->
<text class="txt1" font-size="38px" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="0.5em"  stroke="gold" >
  <textPath href="#textPath1" startOffset="1">
    <tspan dy="0.35em">Loading . . .</tspan>
  </textPath>
</text>
   </g>
 </mask>
 </defs>    
  
                          <!-- Вращающаяся дуга с градиентом -->
<circle id="circle" cx="200" cy="200" r="150"  stroke="url(#Lg)" stroke-width="45" stroke-dashoffset="942"  stroke-dasharray="471" fill="none"  stroke-linecap="round" >
    <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     begin="0s" dur="1s"
     values="942;471;235;0"
     keyTimes="0;0.75;0.9;1"
      calcMode="linear"
     repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  
</circle> 
 
              <!-- Поверх дуги Эту дугу прорезает текстовая маска и -->
              <!-- становится видно цветную полосу с градиентом-->
    <path id="textPath" mask="url(#mask)" d="M200 50a150 150 0 0 1 0 300"   fill="none"   stroke="#383838" stroke-width="45" stroke-linecap="round" />
     
</svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: Саш, то что надо....  Супер...  )))))